# End incoming call when sensor receives certain value android

Tags: java, android, service, checkbox

I'm trying to implement a program that ends a call when the magnetic field sensor has been changed by a certain value. I have managed to display a toast to show that the application does detect this when the app is open. 
I now want to expand it so that:

1. When the checkbox is ticked, it runs in the background as a service
   (I'm not sure I've called the service stuff correctly)
2. The sensor should only be listening when there is an incoming call.

Basically, I want my on sensor changed class to be called only when the box is checked and the call is ringing, and the application should check for this even when the app is not open.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

CheckBox calls, texts, events;
TextView one, two, three;
SensorManager sm;
Sensor sensor;
float sensorX, sensorY, sensorZ, sensorX2, sensorY2, sensorZ2;
float ex, why, zed, diff, mdiff;
int count;  
TelephonyManager tm;
AudioManager audio;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    linktoxml();

    sensorX = sensorY = sensorZ = sensorX2 = sensorY2= sensorZ2=0;
    mdiff = -30;
    diff = 30;
    count = 0;


    calls.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
         public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                //turn on call magnets

             if (calls.isChecked()){
                 startService(new Intent());


                 if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING))
                 {
                     sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE); 
                    sensor = sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
                    sm.registerListener(MainActivity.this, sensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
                    audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                     //start listener for magnet    
                  //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Phone Is Riging", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }


             }else{
                 stopService(new Intent());
             }
            }
    });


}
```

Comment: when I try to exit the application or when when I make an incoming call, the application crashes

Comment: You cannot end call in JB, if you still want to do it post your logcat